# How many times is the function (continuously) differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis

$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x^3 \sin(\frac 1x),  & \text{for $x \neq 0$} \\
0, & \text{for $x=0$}
\end{cases}$

The problem I have with this one is that I understand the definition of when a function is differentiable (or at least I think so), but I can't apply it on this function

Comment: What problem(s) do you face?

Comment: Well, look at what happens at 0 - the function is quite nicely behaved outside there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that

$$f'(x)=\begin{cases}
3x^2 sin(\frac 1x)-x\cos(\frac 1x),  & \text{for $x \neq 0$} \\
0 & \text{for $x=0$}
\end{cases}$$

where $$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^3\sin(\frac 1x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0} x\sin(\frac 1x)=0.$$ Note that $f'(x)$ is continuous. Thus, the function is one time continuously differentiable.

Now,

$$f''(0)=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{3x^2 sin(\frac 1x)-x\cos(\frac 1x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0} (3x sin(\frac 1x)-\cos(\frac 1x))$$ doesn't exist, because $ \lim_{x\to 0} \cos(\frac 1x)$ doesn't exist. Thus, the function is not two times differentiable.

Comment: Why is $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} x sin(\frac 1x) = 0$ ?

Comment: Since $\sin(1/x)$ is bounded and $x$ goes to zero. Note that $|x\sin(1/x)|\le |x|\to 0.$

Answer (score 1):

بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم

Continuity can disappear in $0$. Let's check:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}x^3\sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = 3x^2\sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right) - x \cos \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)
$$
It is still continuous in $0$. But since we have term $x \cos \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ it is not differentiable (remember definition).